# Why is my Future implementation blocked after it is polled once and NotReady?

Tags: rust, future

I implemented the future and made a request of it, but it blocked my `curl` and the log shows that `poll` was only invoked once.

Did I implement anything wrong?

```
use failure::{format_err, Error};
use futures::{future, Async};
use hyper::rt::Future;
use hyper::service::{service_fn, service_fn_ok};
use hyper::{Body, Method, Request, Response, Server, StatusCode};
use log::{debug, error, info};
use std::{
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    task::Waker,
    thread,
};

pub struct TimerFuture {
    shared_state: Arc<Mutex<SharedState>>,
}

struct SharedState {
    completed: bool,
    resp: String,
}

impl Future for TimerFuture {
    type Item = Response<Body>;
    type Error = hyper::Error;
    fn poll(&mut self) -> futures::Poll<Response<Body>, hyper::Error> {
        let mut shared_state = self.shared_state.lock().unwrap();
        if shared_state.completed {
            return Ok(Async::Ready(Response::new(Body::from(
                shared_state.resp.clone(),
            ))));
        } else {
            return Ok(Async::NotReady);
        }
    }
}

impl TimerFuture {
    pub fn new(instance: String) -> Self {
        let shared_state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(SharedState {
            completed: false,
            resp: String::new(),
        }));
        let thread_shared_state = shared_state.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let res = match request_health(instance) {
                Ok(status) => status.clone(),
                Err(err) => {
                    error!("{:?}", err);
                    format!("{}", err)
                }
            };
            let mut shared_state = thread_shared_state.lock().unwrap();
            shared_state.completed = true;
            shared_state.resp = res;
        });

        TimerFuture { shared_state }
    }
}

fn request_health(instance_name: String) -> Result<String, Error> {
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    Ok("health".to_string())
}

type BoxFut = Box<dyn Future<Item = Response<Body>, Error = hyper::Error> + Send>;
fn serve_health(req: Request<Body>) -> BoxFut {
    let mut response = Response::new(Body::empty());
    let path = req.uri().path().to_owned();
    match (req.method(), path) {
        (&Method::GET, path) => {
            return Box::new(TimerFuture::new(path.clone()));
        }
        _ => *response.status_mut() = StatusCode::NOT_FOUND,
    }
    Box::new(future::ok(response))
}

fn main() {
    let endpoint_addr = "0.0.0.0:8080";
    match std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let addr = endpoint_addr.parse().unwrap();
        info!("Server is running on {}", addr);
        hyper::rt::run(
            Server::bind(&addr)
                .serve(move || service_fn(serve_health))
                .map_err(|e| eprintln!("server error: {}", e)),
        );
    })
    .join()
    {
        Ok(e) => e,
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    }
}
```

After compile and run this code, a server with port 8080 is running. Call the server with `curl` and it will block:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8080/my-health-scope
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Did I implement anything wrong?

Yes, you did not read and follow [the documentation for the method you are implementing](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.29/futures/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll) (emphasis mine):

> When a future is not ready yet, the `Async::NotReady` value will be returned. In this situation the future will also register interest of the current task in the value being produced. This is done by **calling `task::park`** to retrieve a handle to the current `Task`. When the future is then ready to make progress (e.g. it should be polled again) the **`unpark` method is called on the `Task`**.

As a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), let's use this:

```
use futures::{future::Future, Async};
use std::{
    mem,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};

pub struct Timer {
    data: Arc<Mutex<String>>,
}

impl Timer {
    pub fn new(instance: String) -> Self {
        let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new()));

        thread::spawn({
            let data = data.clone();
            move || {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
                *data.lock().unwrap() = instance;
            }
        });

        Timer { data }
    }
}

impl Future for Timer {
    type Item = String;
    type Error = ();

    fn poll(&mut self) -> futures::Poll<Self::Item, Self::Error> {
        let mut data = self.data.lock().unwrap();

        eprintln!("poll was called");

        if data.is_empty() {
            Ok(Async::NotReady)
        } else {
            let data = mem::replace(&mut *data, String::new());
            Ok(Async::Ready(data))
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = Timer::new("Some text".into()).wait();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

It only prints out "poll was called" once.

You can call `task::current` (previously `task::park`) in the implementation of `Future::poll`, save the resulting value, then use the value with `Task::notify` (previously `Task::unpark`) whenever the future may be polled again:

```
use futures::{
    future::Future,
    task::{self, Task},
    Async,
};
use std::{
    mem,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};

pub struct Timer {
    data: Arc<Mutex<(String, Option<Task>)>>,
}

impl Timer {
    pub fn new(instance: String) -> Self {
        let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new((String::new(), None)));
        let me = Timer { data };

        thread::spawn({
            let data = me.data.clone();
            move || {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
                let mut data = data.lock().unwrap();

                data.0 = instance;
                if let Some(task) = data.1.take() {
                    task.notify();
                }
            }
        });

        me
    }
}

impl Future for Timer {
    type Item = String;
    type Error = ();

    fn poll(&mut self) -> futures::Poll<Self::Item, Self::Error> {
        let mut data = self.data.lock().unwrap();

        eprintln!("poll was called");

        if data.0.is_empty() {
            let v = task::current();
            data.1 = Some(v);
            Ok(Async::NotReady)
        } else {
            let data = mem::replace(&mut data.0, String::new());
            Ok(Async::Ready(data))
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = Timer::new("Some text".into()).wait();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

See also:

- [Why does Future::select choose the future with a longer sleep period first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48735952/155423)
- [Why is `Future::poll` not called repeatedly after returning `NotReady`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43503953/155423)
- [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932137/155423)

Comment: thanks, I'm not very understand that when I read it first time.

Comment: I'm really appreciate your kindly and detail answer ! Thanks very much !